# CMake strange error when using find_package to find SDL2

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2, mingw-w64, msys

I am currently trying to create a CMake-based build system for my application which uses SDL2 for its graphical output.
But when using MSYS to build for Mingw32-w64 I receive very strange error messages.

Consider the following example project. It uses `findSDL2.cmake` found [here on github](https://github.com/brendan-w/collector/blob/master/cmake/FindSDL2.cmake).
(`main.cxx` is just an empty `main` function and a `#include <SDL2.h>`)

```
# Version requirement and project info
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.3)
project(app)

# Try to find libsdl2
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "Include directory: " ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
message(STATUS "Libraries: " ${SDL2_LIBRARY})

# Define target as executable
add_executable(app main.cxx)

# Include own include files
target_include_directories(app PUBLIC ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})

# Link to libraries
target_link_libraries(app  ${SDL2_LIBRARY})

# Require support for at least C++14.
set_property(TARGET app PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
set_property(TARGET app PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

On my test system, using MSYS to build for Mingw64, SDL2 is installed:

```
katharina@k-pc MINGW64 /d/app
$ pkg-config --cflags sdl2
-Dmain=SDL_main -I/mingw64/include/SDL2
```

And **building the project by hand** also works fine:

```
Katharina@k-pc MINGW64 /d/app
$ clang++ -I/mingw64/include/SDL2 -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 main.cxx              
Katharina@k-pc MINGW64 /d/app
$
```

But when using the CMake project to create makefiles, a weird error appears:

```
Katharina@k-pc MINGW64 /d/app/build
$ cmake "MSYS Makefiles" ./..
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.8.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.8.0
/* ... */
-- Found SDL2: mingw32;/mingw64/lib/libSDL2main.a;/mingw64/lib/libSDL2.a

/* My debug output. Note that all paths are correct! */
-- Include directory: /mingw64/include/SDL2
-- Libraries: mingw32/mingw64/lib/libSDL2main.a/mingw64/lib/libSDL2.a
/*   */

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /d/app/build

Katharina@k-pc MINGW64 /d/app/build
$ make -j
Scanning dependencies of target app
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/mingw64/include/SDL2/SDL.h', needed by 'CMakeFiles/app.dir/main.cxx.obj'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/app.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/app.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Katharina@k-pc MINGW64 /d/app/build
$
```

**CMake is actually able to find the exact same compiler flags I use for my manual compile!**
So, what is wrong here? Do I have an error in my project file? This just seems weird!

Comment: What `FindSDL2.cmake` are you using? My impression was that CMake doesn't ship with one. I personally always just used a `SDL2Config.cmake` that just used PkgConfig itself.

Comment: @Cubic I am using this one: [github.com](https://github.com/brendan-w/collector/blob/master/cmake/FindSDL2.cmake). I should add that to the question.

Comment: Are you sure you need `MSYS makefiles` generator and not the `MinGW` one?

Comment: @arrowd Yes, I'm pretty sure. Although I am compiling using Mingw64 compilers (aka native windows target), I am using MSYS2 as a build environment. This means that f.e. Unix-like paths (like `/d/app/`) will be used instead of Windows-like ones (like `D:\app`). This is crucial since MSYS2 expects it that way.

Comment: I don't see where that error could come from. Did you post exact `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: @arrowd Yes I did. And this is my exact same reaction. This is not my first CMake project, and SDL is the thing that stops it from working. It is weird.

Comment: @nshct Please, run `make VERBOSE=1` and then show its output.

Comment: @arrowd Here you go: [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/Qa8QcTQa)

Comment: shouldn't it be `cmake -G"MSYS Makefiles" ./..` instead of `cmake "MSYS Makefiles" ./..` ?

Comment: @Andrey Kamaev You are correct, but that is merely a typo in this post. I always used `-G` to generate the output that you can see here.

Comment: What's the content of `CMakeFiles/app.dir/build.make`?

Comment: @Eduard Wirch http://pastebin.com/a2r4DSZ7